# Is there a code, which summarizes and then labels my bubble chart with it?

Tags: rstudio, plotly, bubble-chart

I am currently working on creating a bubble chart, which shows 2 variables on the x and y axis and a numerical count, which is represented by the size of the bubble.

I'd like to add a label, which shows the summarized count(X_5) in each bubble (e.g. sum. count = 5 -bubble size-> i hover over the bubble and a label appears that shows me the count 5)

I have already created the bubble chart in rstudio and in JMP. In the program JMP it shows me the count when i click on each bubble. Now i'd like to reproduce this in my code in rstudio.

```
p <- plot_ly(Big_excel_sheet, x = ~X_3, y = ~X_4, color= ~X_5,colors = 'Spectral', type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
             marker = list(size = ~X_5, opacity = 0.5)) %>%
  layout(title = 'X_5 per X_4 per X_3',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = T),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = T))

p
```

[This shows what the JMP program does, and how it shows the count when clicking on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfOnc.png)

[This shows what my code produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX5uR.png)

If anything is unclear in this question please let me know and i'll try explain it better.

Thank you!!